# How to access App Analytics with Facebook API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Our app has several analytics functionalities namely custom events. We would like to access them through the API so we could track it on our own backend.

I don't see a way of accessing the app analytics info programatically...

Any way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

There was an endpoint for App Insights, but it is deprecated. Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/4-30-2019-endpoint-deprecations

There does not seem to be any alternative according to the API reference.

Comment: Frustrating that they keep removing API endpoints. Anyway you see I can get that info on my side? To they have a CSV export somewhere? Facebook pixel will work any different? Any approach?

Comment: not that i know of. did you check out the analytics tab for that?

Comment: I guess there is an export option but for every individual event... Could be an (awful) option but let's see. Upvote for the help!